# capillary waves and gravitational waves simulation

Tags: modeling, fluid-simulation

I'm a graduated physics student and I'm going to simulate capillary waves.I have recently tried COMSOL but I couldn't find any method or model which is related to fluid wave simulation and I spent pretty much time on it!After a little search I found Blender software and it seems promising.Is it suitable for my simulation?I need it to be accurate in physics details.

Comment: Try to include more information in your question, which aspects do you want to simulate, what kind of granularity / domain.  (edit your question with this)

Comment: dude.
I am still an undergraduated student but I've heard of a very promissing and free software called OPEN FOAM, which is very suitable to fluid dynamics simulation and it uses operators overload. I hope it may be usefull